# I'm not able to sync gradle , it shows error at line 7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. 

buildscript { 
   repositories { 
      jcenter() 
   }+ 
   dependencies { 
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3' 
     //error here 
     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong 
     // in the individual module build.gradle files 
   } 
} 

allprojects { repositories { jcenter() } } 

task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir } 
apply plugin: 'com.googl
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
buildscript { repositories { jcenter() }+
```

Remove the char `+`